# getting errors installing strongloop

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I am using

```
nodejs 4.2.0. 
npm 2.14.7
```

I am on RHEL.

When I try npm install -g strongloop, I get this :

```
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/home/rbal/Downloads/node-v4.2.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/rbal/Downloads/node-v4.2.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "strongloop"
npm ERR! node v4.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! strong-arc@1.8.8 preinstall: `node .sl-blip.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the strong-arc@1.8.8 preinstall script 'node .sl-blip.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the strong-arc package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node .sl-blip.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls strong-arc
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/rbal/Downloads/node-v4.2.6-linux-x86/npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone tell me why do i get these errors ? I tried to search using error :

```
Failed at the strong-arc@1.8.8 preinstall script 'node .sl-blip.js'
```

but could not find anything.

Comment: How did you install node? Is `node` actually somewhere in your `$PATH`?